# Help with SQL Query to XML output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml

I have the following query:

```
SELECT    
    [ID] AS [NewID]
    , (
       CASE WHEN LEN([MiddleName]) > 0 THEN
          [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + LEFT([MiddleName],1) + '.'
       ELSE
          [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName]
       END
    ) AS [Name]
    , [Title] AS [ProfTitle]
    , CONVERT(CHAR(10),[DepartureDate],111) AS [BorDepart]
    , [LocationOfficeNumber] AS [OfficePhone]
    , [Location]
    , [LocationSection] AS [Sec]
    , [PracticeGroup] AS [PracticeTL]
    , [Email]         
FROM [dbo].[Borrowers]
```

With that, I'd like to find out how I can write a FOR XML query that translate to this output:

```
<sydney>
    <import>
        <template id="Borrower" name="Borrowers">
            <record searchfield="NewID" searchvalue="NewID">
                <field id="NewID">
                    <![CDATA[NEWID]]>
                </field>                
                <field id="Name">
                    <![CDATA[NAME]]>
                </field>                
                <field id="ProfTitle">
                    <![CDATA[Professional Title]]>
                </field>                
                <field id="BorDepart">
                    <![CDATA[YYYY/MM/DD]]>
                </field>                
                <field id="OfficePhone">
                    <![CDATA[office phone]]>
                </field>
                <link id="Location" linkfield="Code">
                    <![CDATA[011]]>
                </link>
                <link id="Sec" linkfield="Term">
                    <![CDATA[SECTION]]>
                </link>
                <link id="PracticeTL" linkfield="Term">
                    <![CDATA[SUBSECTION]]>
                </link>
                <field id="Email">
                    <![CDATA[email]]>
                </field>
            </record>
        </template>
    </import>
</sydney>
```

I've tried all kinds of combinations with FOR XML PATH and FOR XML EXPLICIT and cannot find any answer to it. The closest I came is with this:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT 
       'Borrower' AS '@id'
       , 'Borrowers' AS '@name'
       , (
          SELECT
             'NewID' AS '@searchfield'
             , 'NewID' AS '@searchvalue'
             , [ID] AS 'NewID' --AS [Field!1!CDATA]

             , (
                CASE WHEN LEN([MiddleName]) > 0 THEN
                    [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName] + ' ' + LEFT([MiddleName],1) + '.'
                ELSE
                    [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName]
                END
             ) AS [Name]
             , [Title] AS [ProfTitle]
             , CONVERT(CHAR(10),[DepartureDate],111) AS [BorDepart]
             , [LocationOfficeNumber] AS [OfficePhone]
             , [Location]
             , [LocationSection] AS [Sec]
             , [PracticeGroup] AS [PracticeTL]
             , [Email]        
          FROM [dbo].[Borrowers]
          FOR XML PATH('record'), TYPE
       )
    FOR XML PATH('template'), TYPE
) AS 'import'
FOR XML PATH('sydney'), TYPE
```

Please any help is welcome since I've been stuck with this for a week and cannot find anything.

P.S.: Here's the schema for the Borrowers table:

[image]

Cheers,

Alvaro Costa

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working `FOR XML EXPLICIT` example.  They are a bit harder to code, but I tend to build them up, section by section so they're not so bad:

```
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Borrowers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Borrowers
CREATE TABLE dbo.Borrowers
(
    ID                      INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName               VARCHAR(30),
    MiddleName              VARCHAR(30),
    LastName                VARCHAR(30),
    Title                   VARCHAR(30),
    DepartureDate           DATE,
    LocationOfficeNumber    VARCHAR(30),
    Location                VARCHAR(30),
    LocationSection         VARCHAR(30),
    PracticeGroup           VARCHAR(30),
    Email                   VARCHAR(30)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Borrowers( FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Title, DepartureDate, LocationOfficeNumber, Location, LocationSection, PracticeGroup, Email )
VALUES 
    ( 'Alvaro', 'X', 'Costa', 'Mr', GETDATE(), '000-000', 'Location 1', 'Location Section 2', 'Practice Group 3', 'alvaro@nospam.com' ),
    ( 'w', '', 'Bob', 'Mr', GETDATE(), '000-007', 'Location 2', 'Location Section 3', 'Practice Group 4', 'wBob@nospam.com' )
GO


SELECT
      1             AS Tag
    , NULL          AS Parent
    , NULL          AS [import!1]
    , NULL          AS [template!2!id]
    , NULL          AS [template!2!name]
    , NULL          AS [record!3!searchfield]
    , NULL          AS [record!3!searchvalue]
    , NULL          AS [record!3!sort!HIDE]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- NewID
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- Name
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- ProfTitle
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- BorDepart
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- OfficePhone
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [link!5!id]          -- Location
    , NULL          AS [link!5!linkfield]
    , NULL          AS [link!5!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [link!5!id]          -- Sec
    , NULL          AS [link!5!linkfield]
    , NULL          AS [link!5!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [link!5!id]          -- PracticeTL
    , NULL          AS [link!5!linkfield]
    , NULL          AS [link!5!!CDATA]

    , NULL          AS [field!4!id]         -- Email
    , NULL          AS [field!4!!CDATA]

UNION ALL

SELECT
      2
    , 1
    , NULL
    , 'Borrower'
    , 'Borrowers'
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
      3
    , 2
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'NewID'
    , 'NewID'
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , 'NewID'
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'Name'
    , LastName
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'ProfTitle'
    , Title
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'BorDepart'
    , CONVERT( CHAR(10), DepartureDate, 111 )
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'OfficePhone'
    , LocationOfficeNumber
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      5
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'Location'
    , 'Code'
    , Location
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      5
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'Sec'
    , 'Term'
    , LocationSection
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      5
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'PracticeTL'
    , 'Term'
    , PracticeGroup
    , NULL
    , NULL

FROM dbo.Borrowers

UNION ALL

SELECT
      4
    , 3
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , ID
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 'Email'
    , Email

FROM dbo.Borrowers
ORDER BY [record!3!sort!HIDE]
FOR XML EXPLICIT, ROOT('sydney')
```

HTH

Answer (score 5):

If you do `'NewID' as [field/@id]` you will get a `field` element with an `id` attribute. On the next line you add `B.ID as [field]` to get the value of `ID` as the node value to the `field` node you created on the line before.

```xml
<field id="NewID">1</field>
```

After that you want a new `field` node and to create that you can use a node without a name that has no value `null as [*]` as a separator between `field` nodes.

This is the pattern to use for each field node you want to create.

```sql
'NewID' as [field/@id],
B.ID as [field],
null as [*],
```

Your query would then look like this.

```sql
select 'Borrower' as [template/@id],
       'Borrowers' as [template/@name],
       (
       select 'NewID' as [@searchfield],
              'NewID' as [@searchvalue],

              'NewID' as [field/@id],
              B.ID as [field],
              null as [*],

              'Name' as [field/@id],
              case when len(B.MiddleName) > 0
                then B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName + ' ' + left(B.MiddleName, 1) + '.'
                else B.LastName + ', ' + B.FirstName
              end as [field],
              null as [*],

              'ProfTitle' as [field/@id],
              B.Title as [field]

      from dbo.Borrowers as B
      for xml path('record'), type
      ) as 'template'
for xml path('import'), root('sydney')
```

Result

```xml
<sydney>
  <import>
    <template id="Borrower" name="Borrowers">
      <record searchfield="NewID" searchvalue="NewID">
        <field id="NewID">1</field>
        <field id="Name">Last, First M.</field>
        <field id="ProfTitle">Tit</field>
      </record>
    </template>
  </import>
</sydney>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, creation of CDATA nodes is possible only in the `FOR XML EXPLICIT` mode. Moreover, Microsoft implementation of XML does not respect them, in accordance with W3C recommendations.

Here is a link: [How to get [CDATA] with FOR XML PATH?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/e22efff3-192e-468e-b173-ced52ada857f/how-to-get-cdata-with-for-xml-path)

So, if you truly need this, you'll have to write an ugly monster, and don't even think about the `TYPE` option - it will wipe out all your CDATA sections. Because of this, making it half `explicit` and half `path` will not work, either. My condolences, mate...

**UPD:** Example of how you can rename the output column in `AUTO` and `EXPLICIT` modes. I would recommend serious testing, though:

```
select (
    select top (10) 1 as [Tag], null as [Parent], s.name as [Item!1!Id]
    from master.dbo.spt_values s
    for xml explicit, root('Root')
) as [XMLCol];
```

Comment: Thanks Wolf for answer, however, this approach limits my output to a max length of 8192 characters, so my XML result (which is a big XML) becomes truncated. I know that this is a limitation in SSMS, but the same behavior is noted when I use my ETL tool (Which is not SSIS. This is for an integration project using IntApp Integration Builder). How can we surpass that? I even tried casting to XML, but when I do that, I lose my CDATA references!